# Zend studio - run associated unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, zend-studio

Assume I have:

- MyClass.php which defines MyClass
- MyClassTest.php which defines MyClassTest which extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.

In netbeans (7.2) while in MyClass.php I can hit a keyboard shortcut to have it run any associated unit test. Netbeans will look for any class with the same name and Test as a suffix (e.g. MyClassTest for the class MyClass), and if it finds one it will then run it, if it finds many it will prompt me which one to run.

I find this quite useful and I am wondering if it is possible to do the same in Zend Studio 9?